# How to validate data format, data & focus form fields through function

Tags: javascript

Need help getting this `function` to:

**Validate data format**

**Validate data is existing**

**Focus on missing fields (One at a time is fine)**

The function below is updated from some advice.  It works much better then my original.  Problem though is if email `field` is blank it works great, wont move on until value is put in.  But the other fields will focus correctly, but still allow the func to move to `else`, which just lowers opacity as you can see.

```
function quantity_box() {

    // store all your field names in an array
    var fieldNames = ["EMAIL", "BILLTOFIRSTNAME", "BILLTOLASTNAME"];

    // loop over each field name in that array
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {

    // extract the field name
    var fieldName = fieldNames[i];

    // use the field name to index the form object and get the field itself
    var field = document.forms["billing_form_id"][fieldName];

    // check the field's value to see if it's empty
    if (field.value === '') {
        field.focus();

    // break from our loop, since we've already found an invalid value
    break;

    }else{

      $(".prod_billing_box").delay(0).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 200);
      $(".prod_quantity_box").delay(215).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 200); 

     }
}
```

Also a note.  Even though fields like EMAIL have settings like TextMode="Email" to verify proper format, the above function also ignores that.

Comment: Additional to the excellent answers, I just wanted to point out, that you can only focus on one element at a time. This is almost the literal definition of the word "focus".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood how indexes work. The following line is valid, but not doing what you expect it to.

```
["EMAIL" && "BILLTOFIRSTNAME" && "BILLTOLASTNAME"]
```

What this is actually doing is performing a boolean expression using `and` operations, like you would in an if statement. If you actually run that line in your javascript console, it will print out

```
"BILLTOLASTNAME"
```

Which is still valid, but not what you want.

Instead, you need to loop over all the form fields and check each one to make sure it's valid. If any of the fields are invalid, you can `break` out of the loop.

```
// track if the entire form is valid, start true
var allValid = true;

// store all your field names in an array
var fieldNames = ["EMAIL", "BILLTOFIRSTNAME", "BILLTOLASTNAME"];

// loop over each field name in that array
for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
  // extract the field name
  var fieldName = fieldNames[i];
  // use the field name to index the form object and get the field itself
  var field = document.forms["billing_form_id"][fieldName];
  // check the field's value to see if it's empty
  if (field.value === '') {
    field.focus();
    // our entire form isn't valid
    allValid = false;
    // break from our loop, since we've already found an invalid value
    break;
  }
}

// if we make it this far and allValid is still true...
if (allValid) {
   // perform your "else" code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Soviut - Seems to be working, but a bit glitchy.  I forgot to mention there is an "ELSE" also.  But that shouldn't matter right?  I just keep the "break"  in the "if" statement?  It seems to be focusing on the missing fields, but still jumping to the else.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume you want the "else" statement to only happen if the whole form is valid?

Comment: Yes that would be preferred

Comment: @NewCodeMan I've updated the answer to include how to track if all fields are valid.

Comment: Still isn't working correctly.  It still allows the func to move through to else.

Comment: @NewCodeMan look at the code updates I've made; they show how to check the validity of all fields and handle your "else" condition.

Comment: Just to verify. This is suppose to run through the FOR loop until the IF is satisfied?  And it would continue to FOCUS on missing fields?  I'm wondering if I am missing brackets.  doesn't my orig code look like it needs one more close bracket?  But when I put it creates an error.  Where would I place ELSE in your example, at the end right?

Comment: No, this runs through the loop and bails out if any field is invalid and sets `allValid` to false when it does. However, if it makes it through the entire loop without that inner if conditioning being triggered, then the whole form must be valid, so if `allValid` is still true, and the if condition at the end is met.

Comment: Got it.  This is now highlighting all fields.  Though it still doesn't care what format email is in xxx@xxx.xxx  It will move on as long as there is any text in field.

Comment: if you set the `type="email"` it will need to be a valid email format. You've probably got it as `type="text"`.

Comment: What I have now thats not working:         <input type="email" placeholder="EMAIL" title="Contact's email (format: xxx@xxx.xxx)" id="email_id" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*" TextMode="Email" required minlength="3" maxlength="45" name="EMAIL" tabindex="8"/>

Comment: Remove the `pattern`. It's conflicting with the default email validation. Anyways, this is going way beyond the original scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility worth noting is that all of this can be done with no javascript whatsoever using HTML5 form field validators. As long as you wrote your form fields in a `<form>` tag, you can add validators such as `required` to a field and the form will not submit, as well as display validation warnings, until the validators all pass.  Below is a working example.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" required placeholder="Must fill me in"><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" required> Must be checked<br/>

  <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" required> One must be chosen<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="radiogroup"> One must be chosen 2<br/>

  <input type="email" placeholder="Must be an email if filled"><br/>

  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It's also possible to query the form element itself and as it if it's valid, as well as use `:valid` CSS form selectors to style valid and invalid fields.

Comment: Great point.  But would it still work if this is just a BUTTON and not SUBMIT?  This BTN just removes DIV tags so users can see other form fields.  Using SUBMIT was making that actually submit.

Comment: @NewCodeMan You should edit your original question and explain more clearly what you're trying to do. It isn't clear.

Comment: Ok let me look at it now

Comment: I have updated the post with your advice also.  If you have time can you take a look and see what best approach would be - Thanks